# Why do i not get any Value when i send a Post Request in Asp.net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, api, rest, webapi

I have been trying for hours but no luck.

I have form to add or edit my book.
when i insert book information and press sumbit. I have only bookImage and nothing else.
when i check my data from PostMan, I see all the values are null except for Book Image.

```
     public class BookController : Controller
{


    string apiUrl = "http://localhost:8080/";
    

    public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {
        List<Book> BookInfo = new List<Book>();
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(apiUrl);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = await client.GetAsync("api/books");
            if (responseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var BookResponse = responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
                {
                    NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
                    MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Ignore
                };
                
                BookInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Book>>(BookResponse, settings);
            }
            return View(BookInfo);
        }
    }

    public ActionResult AddOrEdit(long id = 0)
    {

        if(id == 0)
        {
            return View(new Book());
        }
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8080/api/");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("books" + id.ToString()).Result;
            return View(response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Book>().Result);                
        }
       
        
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddOrEdit( Book book)
    {

        if (book.BookId == 0)
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8080/api/");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsJsonAsync("books", book).Result;

                TempData["SuccessMessage"] = "Employee saved successfully";
                
            }
        }
```

I am getting my Rest Api from Spring Boot.

this is the form

```
    @model BookShop_mvc.Models.Book
    @{
    ViewBag.Title = "AddOrEdit";
    }
    <div class="form-body">
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.BookId)

    <div class="form-group">

        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BookTitle)
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.BookTitle)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BookTitle)
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">

        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BookAuthor)
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.BookAuthor)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BookAuthor)
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">

        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BookPages)
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.BookPages)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BookPages)
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">

        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BookDescription)
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.BookDescription)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BookDescription)
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">

        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BookIsbn)
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.BookIsbn)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BookIsbn)
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">

        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.bookImageContentType)
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.bookImageContentType)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.bookImageContentType)
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">

        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BookPrice)
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.BookPrice)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BookPrice)
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn button" />
        <input type="reset" value="Reset" class="btn button" />
    </div>
}
```

```
        @section scripts{
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
      }
```

this is postman when i hit submit i get no value [image: this is postman that all the values are null]

and this is the site when i retun to index the last 2 books have no value other than image
[image: as you can see the last 2 books does not have any name, price, description]

Comment: Could you share your model code? (BookShop_mvc.Models.Book)

Answer (score 0):

Solved it

I just had to change my variable names instead of BookId -> bookId and Bookauthor -> bookAuthor